# Can a Paver Sitting wall be put on a Paver Patio

Tags: walls, patio

I have a paver patio that was put in my backyard 16x20.  I was wondering if I would be okay to install a sitting wall made out of pavers on top of the paver patio that is already there?  I know it is custom to build a wall on the ground with a standard paver base (gravel, stone) but since that was already done for the patio can I install the walls directly on the existing pavers?  Would I need to create any support for the wall other than adhesive?

FYI I live in Ohio so I will be experiencing freeze/thaw.

Answer (score 1):

Well chances are you can build a wall. If your patio was built right, it was placed on the proper amount of gravel. You would likely know if it was built on gravel if the patio is 5+ years old and it has not heaved much. As long as you are not building a wall higher than 4 or 5 layers, there should be plenty of strength. You should not need any other support for a shorter (5 layer) wall besides masonry construction adhesive between each layer.